# Str_replace special character mail template

Tags: php

I have a email template but i want dear text replace from textarea.
i'm use str_replace to edit text.

If use this code and content have character

`'` result is `\'`

```
$html =str_replace('{{dear}}',$content,$html);
```

if use code

```
$html =str_replace(array('\'', "'"), '', $html);
```

result all image url error.

Comment: PHP doesn't add backslashes to strings by itself. Something else is doing that. Are you sure there are really backslashes in there? If you use `json_encode()` it escapes some special characters, but they'll be decoded when you use `json_decode()` so the right thing should happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stripslashes` function and `$html =str_replace("'", '', $html);`

**PS**

OR In your Code use the below line.

```
$html =str_replace(array("\'", "'"), array('',''), $html);
```